# I am facing sfdx: Autorize a dev hub failed to run

Tags: lightning-web-components

how to solve this problem, I also tried powershell also i can't found any solution.
[image: sfdx: Autorize a dev hub failed to run.]

Comment: What is the edition of your Dev Hub Org?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use Salesforce DX, which connects to your Dev Hub and other orgs over the REST API, against an org that does not support the REST API. You may be using Professional Edition or an org in which that feature has been deactivated for some other reason.

You can [enable Dev Hub](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx) in a Trailhead Playground org or Developer Edition to successfully complete Lightning Web Component trails and example projects.